# Connecting to DBpedia endpoint behind a Proxy firewall

Tags: java, semantic-web, jena, dbpedia

I am working on a project that uses the DBpedia datasets and I would like to connect to them remotely via the sparql endpoints they provide. Now I have to work behind the college proxy server and I cant get my code to connect to the DBpedia sparql endpoints. I am have so far tried to set in the proxy settings via System.getProperties()  but it still doesnt  work and throws an unknown host exception. I have attached my code segment below along with the exception thrown. Any suggestion would be welcome.

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet","true");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "http://username:pwd@172.31.1.6");
System.getProperties().put("proxyPort",8080);
String q= "SELECT ?p ?o WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mendelian_inheritance> ?p    ?o . }";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(q);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
while (results.hasNext()) {
QuerySolution result = results.nextSolution();
RDFNode s = result.get("s");
RDFNode p = result.get("p");
RDFNode o = result.get("o");
System.out.println( " { " + s + " " + p + " " + o + " . }");
}
```

The exception that is being thrown is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" HttpException: java.net.UnknownHostException: dbpedia.org: java.net.UnknownHostException: dbpedia.org
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:203)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:144)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:141)
    at project6.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dbpedia.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
....
```

Just as a footer I have tried setting the sparql url to http://dbpedia.org/snorql

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use "http.proxyPort" instead of "proxyPort". :-)
And, System has a setProperty(String key, String value) method you can use.

Comment: ahh, apologies on tht one tried it and it still isnt working.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove Jena, DBPedia and just try to use URL and openConnection to see if you can actually use your web proxy from a Java program. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yup, try to get a simple URL connection going first. The problem isn't about DBpedia but about your proxy settings.